# Using sqlalchemy dburi with Oracle using External Password Store?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, turbogears

I am trying to get a oracle sqlalchemy dburi working with an external password store (Oracle Wallet)

I have tried using the standard sqlplus syntax for a external password store with no luck..

```
sqlalchemy.dburi="oracle:///@PROD"
```

I can connect successfully using sqlplus as follows:

```
sqlplus /@PROD
```

I can't find any information on how to use external password stores with sqlalchemy or turbogears?

Comment: Did you get it working? if yes, could you please post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top comment: Make sure you are running version 5.2.1+ of cx_oracle (http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html). Prior to that a bug in SessionPools existed.

Comment: I am able to get cx_Oracle to connect just fine using the wallet alias:

import cx_Oracle

db = cx_Oracle.connect("/@PROD")
print db.version

db.close()


I just need to know how to put "/@PROD" in a URI format for sqlalchemy..

Answer (score 0):

Based off digging through the source code for sqlalchemy, the correct way to do this is to set the `username` property (not the `database` property) of the `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL` to your TNS alias for your wallet.

With `sqlalchemy.engine.url.make_url`

```py
import sqlalchemy.engine.url

url = url.make_url('oracle+cx_oracle://')
url.username = '/@PROD'
engine = create_engine(url)
```

With `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL`

```py
import sqlalchemy.engine.url

url = url.URL('oracle+cx_oracle', username='/@PROD')
engine = create_engine(url)
```

This is because ultimately, for cx_Oracle to use an Oracle Wallet, you must use the `user` parameter in `cx_Oracle.connect`.

e.g.

```
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='/@PROD')
# Because the first parameter in connect is user, the following is also valid
# connection = cx_Oracle.connect('/@PROD')
```